# ¿Cómo limpiar las cajas de texto de un formulairo después de enviar los datos? PHP

Tags: php, html, email, input, text

Tengo un formulario en HTML el cual al llenarlo y darle clic en el botón enviar, se envía un email con php. Los datos se envían correctamente y el email llega sin problemas pero, las cajas de texto se quedan con los datos que se escribieron.
¿Qué puedo hacer para que las cajas de texto se limpien al momento de darle click al botón enviar.

//Código php

```
<?php

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  //aquí tengo los encabezados

  $msj = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $name . " \r\n";
  $msj .= "Correo electrónico: " . $email . " \r\n";
  $msj .= "Asunto: " . $subject . " \r\r";
  $msj .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['message'] . " \r\r";
  $msj .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y (H:i:s)', time());

  $to = 'micorreo';
  $asunto = 'Mensaje enviado a través de ..';

  $envio = mail($to, $asunto, utf8_decode($msj), $header);

  if($envio) {
    $resul = '<h4>El mensaje fue enviado exitosamente. Gracias.</h4>';
  } else {
    $resul = '<h4>ERROR. No se pudo enviar el mensaje.</h4>';
  }

  echo $resul;

?>
```

Comment: Que estas usando para el envio?

Comment: Si estás usando AJAX, debes vaciar las cajas con JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar a poner la función `header()` nativa de PHP dentro de tu condicional para ejecutarse si la comprobación es correcta.

Te dejo el link a la documentación de PHP, en donde estará explicado de mejor forma que la que podría decirte aquí, Mucha suerte en tu proyecto :)

[Ir a la documentación de PHP para `header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

Esta función lo que hace es cambiar la url la que especifiques, pero personalmente usaría JS para recargar la página, te dejaré un ejemplo de una implementación que realicé, muy similar a la que tienes

```html
$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuarios
        (userID, userName, userLast, userColegio, userRegion, userCarrera, userUniversidad, userGrado, userCedula, userMaestria, userDoctorado, userEspecialidad, imgName, fechaReg)
        VALUES ('$cedula','$nombre','$apellidos','$colegioTransformado','$region','$licenciatura','$universidad','$grado','$cedula','$maestria','$doctorado','$especialidad', '$imgName','$fechaReg')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex, $consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
            $newName = $nombre . " " . $apellidos . ".jpeg";
            $ruta = "img/users/" . $newName;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $ruta);

            echo ('<div class="text-center ok p-3"><h3>¡REGISTRO EXITOSO!</h3></div>');
?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                setTimeout('inputOK()', 0);
                setTimeout('goHome()', 4000);

                function inputOK() {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        titleText: 'Éxito',
                        html: '¡Registro exitoso, tu información ha sido guardada!<br><small>Volviendo a la página de inicio</small>',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        allowEscapeKey: false
                    });
                };

                function goHome() {
                    location.replace('http://localhost/proyectos/FORMULARIO%20SERVER/');
                };
            </script>
        <?php
        } else {
            echo ('<div class="text-center bad p-3"><h3>OOPS... HA HABIDO UN ERROR</h3></div>');
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                setTimeout('inputError()', 0);
                setTimeout('recargarPagina()', 4000);

                function inputError() {
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        titleText: 'Error',
                        html: '¡Oops, ha ocurrido un error al enviar tus respuestas!<br><small>Volviendo a la página de inicio</small>',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        allowEscapeKey: false
                    });
                };

                function recargarPagina() {
                    location.replace('http://localhost/proyectos/FORMULARIO%20SERVER/');
                };
            </script>
        <?php
        }
    }
```

Espero que esta información te sea de utilidad, mi intención es que puedas llevar a cabo tu idea.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, tu ejemplo me ayudo bastante y me aclaro algunas dudas que tenía. Saludos. @Arturo Morales

Comment: para eso estamos aquí, xd @kayvos